# const * const * member variable initialization c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having trouble with the initialization of this struct (simplified for example)

```
struct S{ const float * const * const data;};
```

Basically I have a buffer of buffers of floats, and I use const to ensure someone using S cannot change anything to this member (read only).

My problem is that this is complicated and hard to read to initialize, I would like to use a lambda that return an const S, and so I could initialize members in my lambda by writing the member name : `s.data = ptr;`

Now this code is complex and I wonder what could be a better solution.

AFAIK, having `struct S{float ** data;}` a `const S` would not protect as efficiently the content of the member, I could not modify `S::data`, but I could modify `*S::data`.

**How should I do ?**

Thank you

Comment: The line `s.data = ptr;` will never compile no matter what you do because `data` is `const` and can't be assigned to. You'll have to change your design if you want to do that.

Comment: Yes exactly currently I have a specific CTor, but I would prefer to have non const members I do like this : http://herbsutter.com/2013/04/05/complex-initialization-for-a-const-variable/

Comment: this question is fantastic :-) ... +1

Comment: Thank you but I would prefer to know that I m stupid and there is a simple solution, but I did not found it after 3 days

Comment: Why not use `struct S { const float *const *data; };`?  This would let you initialize `S` easily enough, but then you can pass a `const S *` around...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just remove the last `const`?

```
struct S{ const float * const * data;};
```

That way you can initialize `data` however you like, and it still can't be used to modify anything it *points to*.

`data` itself can be modified, but should that be prevented, it should simply be `private`.

Comment: No because, in this cate the user of this struct (that I want to protect) could change data itself, and then all the buffers inside data and all those in data[x] would leak. I agree with you a solution would be to make data private, and add a bunch of getter functions, but if I have to reach that extremity I prefer to simply initialize it in the constructor. My real issue is how to make the interface clearer, and perhaps use a lambda to initialize my const member.

Comment: @dzada: So you what to change `data` easily but you don't want others to be able to do the same uh? You have two options: 1) make it private, maybe in a subclass; 2) make it const and initialize it somehow (but you already know that).

Comment: Yes I want to make it easy and clear to create a struct. (I can with explicit ctor, initializer list but it is not as clear as struct.member = xxx in a lambda) BUT Once my struct is built and passed to a function for instance I want to make it impossible to modify either data either any data[x] or data[x][y].

I modified here my answer because rereading it, I think it could be the best approach. What do you all people think ?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way is to add a constructor to `S`. This allows you to set the value of data in the ctor initializer list.

```
struct S
{
    explicit S(const float *const *const d) : data(d) {}
    const float * const * const data;
};

S GetS()
{
    float **data = GetData();

    return S(data);
}
```

If you want to restrict who can change `S::data` after it has been initialized you can *box* the member variable and use friendship to allow access. This requires encapsulating the `data` member in an additional struct that provides conversion and assignment operators.

```
struct Outer
{
    struct S
    {
    private:

        struct ConstBox
        {
            friend Outer;

            ConstBox(const ConstBox& other) : data_(other.data_) {}
            explicit ConstBox(const float *const *const data) : data_(data) {}
            operator const float* const* () const { return data_; }

        private:

            ConstBox& operator=(const float * const * data)
            {
                data_ = data;
                return *this;
            }

            const float * const * data_;
        };


    public:

        S() : data(nullptr) {}
        explicit S(const float *const *const d) : data(d) {}

        ConstBox data;
    };

    S DoSomething() const
    {
        S   s(nullptr);

        auto f = []() -> S
        {
            S s;

            s.data = new float*[10];

            return s;
        };

        return f();
    }
};


typedef Outer::S S;

void FailTest()
{
    S   s;

    s.data = nullptr; // <-- fails
    float** v1 = s.data; // <-- fails
    const float** v1 = s.data; // <-- fails
    // These are ok
    const float* const* v2 = s.data;
}
```

Comment: But `S(data)` won't compile because `data` is not a `const float * const *`.

Comment: The explicit CTor :yes, I agree. In fact I don't need to do that as the generated initializer list does it already. But my point, is that it is less clear to read, than `s.data = xxx` especially if you have a lot of members in the struct
Yes @rodrigo, the `GetS()` would not compile. I was commenting the idea of the explicit CTor

Comment: @dzada There are a lot of different ways to approach this problem, using a constructor is just one. I think if you included an example of how you want to create and mutate `S` inside of your lambda it will be easier  to provide a solution closer to what you are looking for

Comment: @rodrigo `float **` can be converted to `float const * const *`. This compiles just fine for me.

Comment: @dzada Based on your additional comments I added an additional solution that more closely matches what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

@CaptainObvious's answer is the correct one. Write a constructor for S, taking whatever arguments it needs, and use a member initialiser rather than an assignment statement to set 'data'.

Comment: yes I know that i can do that, my problem is that it is not clear when you have 20 members in the struct to write them in order, it is clearer to write strust.member = . But if I do that I loose the const protection. This interface is for a client I want it simple and protected

Comment: Was just about to undelete it too. Gotta make a few updates but as you said it's about as correct as you can get without removing the final const CV qualifier from `data`

Comment: I'm not sure we need an answer that just says someone else's answer is correct with nothing significant added.

Answer (score 0):

With your simplified example I would simply do:

```
struct S{ float const * const * const data;};

auto create_buffer() -> float const * const * {
    float **buf;
    /* ... compute buffer contents */
    return buf;
}

S s {create_buffer()};
```

However, in a comment you mention that you have many members and that initializing members based on order is not sufficiently clear.

```
struct S { const A a; const B b; const C c; };

S s {x,y,z}; // order based, not readable enough.
```

`const` members *must* be initialized as part of the object's construction. You must either specify them somehow in the initializer, or you must set their value in the class, so that they are set at construction time.

---

### Solution 1

One way to pass them during construction, but in a readable fashion is to use a second object to help initialization:

```
struct S_initializer { A a; B b; C c; }

struct S {
  const A a; const B b; const C c;
  S(S_initializer &s) : a(s.a), b(s.b), c(s.c) {}
};

S make_S() {
  S_initializer s;
  s.a = x;
  s.b = y;
  s.c = z;
  return S{s};
}
```

The above involves some repitition, which you can avoid by just making the initialization helper object a const member of S:

```
struct S {
  const S_initializer m;
  S(S_initializer &s) : m{s} {}
};

S make_S() {
  S_initializer s;
  s.a = x;
  s.b = y;
  s.c = z;
  return S{s};
}
```

The tradeoff is that now to access the members of S you have to have an extra `.m` in there:

```
A a = s.m.a; // versus just s.a;
```

---

### Solution 2

A second method relies on a compiler extension; Although not standard C++, gcc and clang implement C99 designated initializers in C++. VC++ does not implement this.

```
S s { .a = x, .b = y, .c = z };
```